# What are the properties of 3-dimensional split-complex numbers?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, hypercomplex-numbers

I have often encountered claims that 3-dimensional numbers are impossible. But
it seems to me that $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Hadamard multiplication should in fact behave quite similar to split-complex numbers. I wonder, whether this is true or not and what would be the system's properties.

First of all, we know that the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ of pairs $(a,b)$ with Hadamard product is isomorphic to the split-complex numbers of the form $\frac{a+b}{2}+j\frac{a-b}{2}$.

Now, what happens in 3 dimensions? A space $\mathbb{R}^3$ seems to form a nice hypercomplex numbers system with $(1,1,1)$ being the multiplicative identity, which we can equate to the real number $1$.
The system has zero divisors but no nilpotents, so in structure it should be similar to the split-complex numbers.

I was unable though to find an orthogonal basis, in which one element is $(1,1,1)$ and the two other elements have the same length, but I believe such basis should exist (and not being single).

That said, I wonder

1. **Main qestion:** Does such space have subspaces isomorphic to split-complex numbers that has identity $1=(1,1,1)$ and $j^2=1$ (I guess, no)?
2. Is there an example of a basis that has the properties outlined above? What about such basis where the two other elements except $(1,1,1)$ have similar representations in canonical basis?
3. What are the general algebraic properties of such numbering system and to what extent it is similar to split-complex numbers?

Comment: You asked a related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420893/can-mathbbr3-with-hadamard-product-be-represented-as-matrices#comment1081214_420893) before.  As I [said](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1081214), same length+orthogonal is easy; for example, $\{(1, 1, 1), (\sqrt{3/2}, -\sqrt{3/2}, 0), (\sqrt{1/2}, \sqrt{1/2}, -\sqrt2)\}$. (If you want length $1$, then $(\sqrt{1/2}, \sqrt{1/2}, 0)$ and $(\sqrt{1/6}, \sqrt{1/6}, -\sqrt{1/3})$.)  So there must be something more that you want.  I guess it's the "similar representations" in (2), but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the examples. By similar representations I meant that their representations in canonical basis should have similar coefficients. Here we have one having one coordinate 0 and the other having all coordinates non-zero. I think such "symmetric" representation is not possible though.

Comment: It's easy enough to have all co-ordinates non-$0$; for example, you could take $\{(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, -3), (-5, 4, 1)\}$, which you can then normalise to make the basis vectors have any length that you please.  Could you give a precise, mathematical criterion according to which a basis is satisfactory?  Without one, it's hard to invest much effort into finding one which may turn out not to meet an unspecified condition.

Comment: @LSpice so, if we have a system where $z=a+bj_1+cj_2$ where $1=(1,1,1), j_1=(\sqrt{1/2}, \sqrt{1/2}, 0), j_2=(\sqrt{1/6}, \sqrt{1/6}, -\sqrt{1/3})$, what are its properties? Does it have a subring isomorphic to split-complex numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you hope to gain by phrasing things [that way](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421077/what-are-the-properties-of-3-dimensional-split-complex-numbers#comment1081725_421077).  No matter what basis you use, it's the same algebraic structure, namely, $\mathbb R^3$.  Certainly there is a subring isomorphic to the split-complex numbers, namely, the one spanned by $(1, 1, 0)$ (or $(1, 1, 1)$ if you want your subring to have the same identity as the ambient ring) and $(1, -1, 0)$.

Comment: @LSpice possibly the representation is similar if the coordinates of one basis vector are the same as the other one after switching 2 of the 3 coordinates or the same but with opposite sign, something like this. At least the absolute values of the coordinates should be the same, not 1,2,3 vs 5,4,1.

Comment: [That](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421077/what-are-the-properties-of-3-dimensional-split-complex-numbers#comment1081730_421077) is a question about cross products, which you can easily answer yourself:  the third vector must be a multiple of $(1, -2, 1)$.  I'm not sure you want the $j$ you have indicated, since the [usual presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) of the split complex numbers requires $j^2 = 1$.

Comment: @LSpice well, so there is no subring, isomorphic to the split-complex numbers that has the identity $1=(1,1,1)$ and $j^2=1$?

Comment: @LSpice added this to the question.

Comment: Certainly there [is](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1081737); I have [given one](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1081726). You have mentioned concerns about length, but I'm not sure why; the split-complex numbers are not a normed ring in the usual (metric) sense of the word, and, if you want to impose a norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$, then we surely must have $\lVert1\rVert = 1$, whereas the Euclidean norm of $(1, 1, 1)$ is $\sqrt3$, so already whatever norm you impose cannot agree with the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @LSpice in your example it seems that $j^2\ne(1,1,1)$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry; you are [right](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1081750), and I was thinking of $(1, 1, 0)$ and $(1, -1, 0)$.  The subring spanned by $(1, 1, 1)$ and, say, $(1, 1, -1)$ does the job.  If you want, as I have taken you to suggest, $j$ to be Euclidean-orthogonal to $1$ (which, again, is extra structure, not intrinsic to the split-complex numbers), then you can verify that this can't be achieved just by observing that the inner product of any square root $(\pm1, \pm1, \pm1)$ of $(1, 1, 1)$ with $(1, 1, 1)$ is (in $\mathbb Z$ and) $3$ modulo $2$.

Comment: @LSpice thanks! This is very informative and will make a good answer!

Comment: @LSpice my idea is to find an orthogonal basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that would include (1,1,1) and be somewhat more interesting than others.

Comment: @Anixx: Low-dimensional associative algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ are easy to classify: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Classification_of_low-dimensional_unital_associative_algebras_over_the_complex_numbers . Now, proceed similarly over $\mathbb{R}$ in coordinate-free way. This limit the possibilities/tries substantially. From there it should be easy to check if you can find a 3-dimensional algebra with your desired properties (whatever they are) after a choice of coordinates/explicit basis.

Answer (score -2):

**Answering my own question, but if I am wrong, please, correct.**

Intuition. Basically, if you add two complex dimensions to reals, say $i$ and $j$, you automatically get a fourth dimension $ij$ because this number cannot be expressed using only the three dimensions. The system you get then is called bicomplex numbers and 4-dimensional.

On the other hand, if you add two split-complex dimensions to reals, say $j$ and $k$, you do not get a fourth dimension automatically because we can define $jk=j+k-1$, which can be expressed in the already existing 3 dimensions. Thus, you get a 3D algebra.

It seems that each of the two added split-complex dimensions are isomorphic to the classic split-complex axis.

As user @LSpice has pointed out, these two split-complex unities would not be orthogonal in the canonical basis, but this is not a problem from the point of view of algebraic properties.

---

Construction and properties

Take $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Hadamard product. In other words, triplets of numbers with element-wise multiplication.

Now assign $(1,1,1)=1,(-1,1,1)=j, (1,1,-1)=k$.

A number would be written in the form $a+bj+ck$. Algebraically it will be a commutative ring with zero divisors (hence, not a field, but that's OK). For instance $(j-1)(k-1)=0$.

Here is a Mathematica code to experiment with:

```
Unprotect[Power]; Power[0, 0] = 1; Protect[Power];
$Pre = (# /. {j -> {-1, 1, 1}, k -> {1, 1, -1}}) /. {x_, y_, z_} -> 
     x/2 + z/2 + (j (y - x))/2 + (k (y - z))/2 &;
```

Using this code one can see that

$j^2=k^2=1$

$jk=j+k-1$

$\log (j+k+1)=\frac{1}{2} j \log (3)+\frac{1}{2} k \log (3)$

$j^j=j^k=j$

$k^k=k^j=k$

$\sqrt{j+k}=\frac{j}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}}$

$0^{j+k}=1-\frac{j}{2}-\frac{k}{2}$

The division formula would be:

$\frac{a_1+b_1 j+c_1 k}{a_2+b_2 j+c_2 k}=\frac{j}{2}  \left(\frac{a_1+b_1+c_1}{a_2+b_2+c_2}-\frac{a_1-b_1+c_1}{a_2-b_2+c_2}\right)+\frac{k}{2}  \left(\frac{a_1+b_1+c_1}{a_2+b_2+c_2}-\frac{a_1+b_1-c_1}{a_2+b_2-c_2}\right)+\frac{a_1+b_1-c_1}{2 \left(a_2+b_2-c_2\right)}+\frac{a_1-b_1+c_1}{2 \left(a_2-b_2+c_2\right)}$

If we add a complex unity $i$, we will get a 6-dimensional number system.

Particularly, we will see that

$i^{j+k}=1-j-k$

and

$\log (j k)=i\pi-\frac{i \pi  j}{2}-\frac{i \pi  k}{2}$